# Нужна помощь с настройкой плагина - jquerymaskedinput

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно выставить маску с конкретным кодом страны - `+998`, но в инпуте отображается только `+__8`, как это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$.mask.definitions['9'] = '';
$.mask.definitions['d'] = '[0-9]';
$("#phone").mask("+998 ddd dd dd");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
<input id="phone" type="text" />
```